# Remove a device from 'Find My iPhone' app

Tags: find-my-iphone

I cannot remove any devices from the list of devices in the 'Find My iPhone' app.

I have also looked on iCloud.com and cannot seem to remove them there either. Is this possible outside of MobileMe?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of people who have done it, or *how* to do it?

Comment: @DanielL this was answered and accepted 6 days ago.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. Didn't see that in my clean up. I was looking at short questions and trying to make sure they all contained enough info to be answered, and missed that this one already was. Carry on!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have physical access to the device, to into the iCloud settings and turn off "Find My iPhone". If you don't, You can remove devices from iCloud.com, provided iCloud can't find them. Go to the "Find My iPhone" section on iCloud.com. Click the device to select it, then click the circled "X" on the right. This removes the device from Find My iPhone.

[image]

You can also remove devices from the Find My iPhone app by swiping horizontally on the device. Again, the device must not be locatable for this to work.

[image]

Comment: Can this be done if the devices are found?

Comment: Not that I can tell, the X doesn't appear if they're found for some reason.

Comment: This has been bugging me for a while, as one of the devices is now my girlfriends and I don't want it in the list, although handy in a creepy way!?

Comment: Current girlfriend? Ask to borrow her phone and go into "iCloud" and turn off "Find My iPhone". Ex girlfriend? Remote wipe :)

Comment: Haha, Current. Great shout.